# IE problems regarding opacity, stacking order and a disaperaing div

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index, opacity

I am having bit of a trouble regarding my code in IE, everything works great in Safari and Firefox, but not in IE.

My first problem is that some of my divs are placed behind other divs, I have tried to change the `z-index`, but to no good. Since these divs are `position: absolute`, I don't think it will help changing the `div` order in the HTML either.

The second problem is that I am not able to get the opacity to work in IE, I have tried the `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";` and
`filter:alpha(opacity=80);` but to no help. The Opacity doesn't work on anything in IE.

The third problem is that one of my images has disappeared completely, the image inside the `div="kart"` is nowhere to be found in IE. I have applied `float:left;` to the `div`, so it is supposed to line up under the other div in that section when the side scales. I find it rather strange, every other `img` on my site is working fine, I have tried changing the file format, but again, to no good.

I would appreciate if someone could take a look at it, I am self-taught and don't have anyone to ask about these kind of things.

And apologies for my poor English, I'm foreign..:)

Not sure if I should include the HTML-markup and the CSS-styles, so I will just give you the url for starters.

The site is located at http://www.vstil.com

Comment: IE + opacity == always a nightmare. :(

Comment: Please specify the version(s) of IE you're testing with.

Comment: I am testing IE8 in windows xp

Comment: well done for solving your problems :) If you post the solution as an answer, you can mark it as accepted, which will help others searching for similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured some of my problems out and would like to share it if anyone should have the same problem.

The first problem had to do with the z-index of an element and its parents element. In IE a child-element cant have a higher z-index than its parents element, so I had to set the parents z-indez to 3, and then I could set the childs z-index to 2 and 1 to get them correct.

My second problem with the opacity not working was because IE requiers the layout of the element to be set. The solution was therefor to set the width and height of the element which I had assigned opacity to.

The third problem of the disapearing div I have not yet figured out, also the site has been moved from the server and can now be found at www.fanafysioterapi.no

*Edit: Figuered out the third problem too, which was simular to the first. The div was hidden behind another div, because some of the divs had position relative/absolute and some had not. Found the answare to my problem here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

over and out.